# Знаем ли мы (,) на что идём? Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Совершенно запуталась. Помогите, пожалуйста! Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении? И почему нужна или не нужна, объясните, пожалуйста, чтобы я больше об этом не спрашивала. Даже стыдно как-то стало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно нужна. Это же придаточное предложение, со своей грамматической основой.
Я просто затрудняюсь понять причину ваших сомнений.

Ну вот сравните.
***Знаем ли мы, на что (мы) идем.***
Это грамматически эквивалентно
***Знаем ли мы, на что они идут.***
Так понятнее?

Comment: Да, спасибо! Даже не знаю, почему так получилось. Пишу повесть, и на тебе. Запнулась на одном предложении с запятой. Вы очень мне помогли.